# Export JavaFX project as executable jar or exe

Tags: java, javafx, export, exe, executable-jar

Hi I've finished my JavaFx project and now I want to export it as a .exe file

The problem is that my JavaFX project use VM arguments

```
--module-path D:\ProjectDirectory\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

I export the executable jar file and I try to run it with the argument like this

```
java -jar D:\Project.jar --module-path D:\ProjectDirectory\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

When I execute that program I receive the next error

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Comment: The `-jar [jar-file]` must be the _last_ JVM argument. Anything after that is considered arguments to _your application_, not the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to use the jpackage tool to package your application. Have a look at the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/packaging-overview.html